# Google's "More results from domain" don't include subdomain which causes rewritten titles

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, yoast

Okay so, Google has this thing where when you search for a company it comes up with the result, a few categories from the result and then a link that reads, "More results from domain.com".

[image]

My domain is one.za.com, however, for me, that little "More results from" thing is showing only za.com, which is only partial. So now, when that link is clicked on, the SEO done on every page is overlooked and replaced by the search term.

[image]

If you consider the highlighted result in the snip above, you'll notice that despite the resulting page having a full meta title and description set in the backend, it's showing the search term instead.

[image]

This doesn't seem to happen for every page that's been SEO'd, and it seems to be random, i.e, when I try this again tomorrow, different results will show the incorrect title.

I know this happens because of the search terms, and the search term being za.com, so my question is, how do I change that "More results from domain" to be my full domain name, i.e one.za.com and not just za.com?

I've read some stuff and things and deduced that a robots file might be what's needed. Only, I'm not entirely certain what to put in this robots file to fix that "More results from domain" link to include my entire domain name.

My site is built in Wordpress using Yaost for the SEO.

Comment: What do you mean by "include my entire domain name"?   Do you mean you want it to search "one.za.com" or "www.one.za.com"?   Is "za.com" not entirely your site, ie, your site is just the "one" subdomain of that site?

Comment: That is correct yes. Instead of it searching just za.com, I'd like for it to search one.za.com. That'd surely be a massive relief. Since I don't manage the server, I can't definitively confirm that the one in one.za.com is, in fact, a subdomain or not, but I'm 90% sure that it is.

Comment: Google usually considers a "site" to be everything under a domain name.     There may be some exceptions for dynamic DNS domains, but I'm not sure how you would get an exception for a domain.    In any case, is this a big deal?   I highly doubt that many users click on the "more results from" link.

Comment: It isn't a big deal for me since I'm only a developer - but the SEO lady seems to think that it's an incredibly serious issue that if it isn't fixed, it's going to seriously affect the SEO. I agree that not many people actually click on that, and honestly, if it wasn't for this problem, I'd probably never have noticed that link even exists.

Comment: This "More results from domain"; does it actually influence the SEO of a site in any way, shape or form?

Answer (score 1):

`More results from domain` is nothing other then the site-query, like `site:za.com`. You aren't able to change the query kind of how Google does it. What you are able, is to move your content from the subdomain to the main domain - this would trigger displaying this content by querying of `More results from domain`